# How to use the systemd presets in an RPM package

Tags: rpm, systemd, preset

I am reading the Fedora packaging guidelines on using systemd presets but am missing a key point:

The macro %systemd_post runs `systemctl preset` meaning that the information about whether to enable or to disable the service must already be present in the systemd preset files. But where does it go there from in the first place? Should the package first place it own preset file in the location provided (which is not recommended as far as I have read since it complicates the management of the general policy) or add the service being installed into one of the existing systemd preset files? To which then as there are several of them?

I am talking about a self-written service which meets the requirements of being enabled by default and which I would thus like to enable automatically during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About presets:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackagePresets
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html

Those presets are intended for distribution itself (e.g. some service should be enabled for Workstation, but not for Server).
Your 3rd party package will never be enabled.
So if you really think it should be enabled (think twice) then you simply enable it in %post.
This will be rejected if you would like to get your package into Fedora, but I guess that that is not your case.

Comment: Now I see, thank you very much. I somehow overlooked the fact that the preset files related only to the services shipped with the OS distribution, not the ones the user himself builds and runs on a particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

Preset files are also distributed by integrators.

An integrator can design a commercial service ("solution") which requires a number of software packages to be installed and configured to work (integrate) with each other, in order to provide the functionality of the solution. The integrator would then supply a list of of packages, a set of configuration files, and service presets that taken as a set implement the "solution"

Eg. Say that the "solution" is an authenticated git server providing SSH push/pull, webgui, and bugzilla running on CentOS. He would specify lighttpd, git, openssh-server and bugzilla, ldap-server, and rsyslog, and maybe some private RPMs. He would create the config files for all these components to interoperate, and decide which services should be running and with what parameters. Then he can package all this configuration somehow (perhaps in a convenient RPM, or a puppeteer script, etc), so that the solution owner can deploy it as an "app" or "turnkey solution". One of the things the integrator needs to supply is a preset file, which describes which services should be enabled or disabled to make the solution work.

In this case the "vendor" is the solution provider, which is not the distro, nor the administrator. Presets are a specification made by the integrator.

If your RPM installs an instanced service, I have looked into the question of instanced services installed on CentOS 7 in [How to preset service instances in RPM spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76994392/how-to-preset-service-instances-in-rpm-spec/77069193#77069193)