# How to preset service instances in RPM spec

Tags: systemd, rpm-spec

I am building a private application packaged with RPM, which will be installed on systems that contain the following .preset file statement like `enable me-backend@.service 2 4 12` as an administrative setting in `/etc/systemd/system-preset/reviewer-app.preset`; each system specifies a different set of instances.

The installed systemd is `systemd-219-78.el7`

I would like that upon installing the "me-backend" RPM, the proper "systemctl preset 'me-backend@*'" to activate exactly the administratively prescribed instances.

This wildcard command line does not work. It succeeds (returns 0) without activating any services. I've tried various combinations like "me-backend@*.service", "me-backend@", with no success. Variations without an instance name fail with 'Failed to execute operation: Unit name me-backend@.service is missing the instance name.', and those with wildcards succeed without doing anything.

I expected that instances me-backend@2, me-backend@4 and me-backend@12 to be enabled, by creating symbolic links like '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/me-backend@2.service' for each of the 3 services.

Another approach I tried is "preset-all", however this resets presets on all installed applications, which is wrong for my package to do. I think my package should only touch services/instances that it provides.

What is the right incantation of the systemctl preset command that the rpm spec should run in order to enable the administratively-preset instances of this service at installation time?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob, sorry if the question is not clear, I am looking to build a package of an application targeted at a system that happens to run systemd. Unlike an end user's need to create a service for some arbitrary executable, I need to deliver (package) a service ready to start, conforming to the systemd ecosystem. My question is not very different from one asking how to use GCC to build an app using static linking rather than dynamic. More precisely, the question is not at all about how to write a unit file, rather how to run the tool (systemctl) to activate/enable a given unit file.

Comment: @Rob, I'm not looking for a command line that a sysadmin might run, but for one that a developer would incorporate in their application/package. Another way to ask it would be "how to package my app so it installs and and works correctly on...", which I think is a programming question. There are similar RPM questions on on stackoverflow, but none on unix.

Answer (score 1):

I have [answered my own related question from StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/756099/389552) - the answer is that RPMs that target systemd 219 (such as CentOS 7 rpms) cannot rely on the "systemctl preset myservice@.service" syntax because systemd 219 does not support instance presets.

The answer to the question here ("how to write an RPM spec that presets service instances") is:

#### Step 1

The syntax `enable me-backend@.service 2 4 12` is not valid on CentOS 7 because this feature was not yet supported by systemd 219. Instead, the sysadmin must list the required instances in a local `me-backend.target` override file using the `Requires=` pragma. The integrator must list `enable me-backend.target` in the presets file.

Example `/etc/systemd/system/me-backend.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Me backend %I-bit
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target
Requires= \
  me-backend@2.service \
  me-backend@4.service \
  me-backend@12.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Integrator specifies that `me-backend.target` preset is enabled in `/etc/systemd/system-preset/reviewer-app.preset`:

```
enable me-backend.target
```

#### Step 2

Developer packages in the RPM:

- `me-backend@.service` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/me-backend@.service`, describing how an instance is started
- default `me-backend.target` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/me-backend.target` listing a reasonable set of default instances on the `Requires=` line as shown above:

#### Step 3

Developer specifies scriptlets that activate the `me-backend.target` preset:

```
%post
%systemd_post %{name}.target

%preun
%systemd_preun %{name}.target

%postun
%systemd_postun %{name}.target
```

#### Explanation

At RPM install time, the installation scriptlets do `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl preset me-backend.target`, triggering the integrator's list of instances to be enabled.

The `me-backend.target` is enabled by the integrator as a preset, and `Requires=` the instances specified by the administrator in the `me-backend.target` `/etc` override.

On systems where the preset is not set, no instances will start, thanks to the distribution's `disable *`

On systems where the preset is set, but the administrator has not listed specific instances in the `/etc/.../me-backend.target` override, the instances deemed reasonable defaults by the developer (ie, the packaged `/usr/lib/.../me-backend.targets`) will start.

**Note:** At least one person voted that this question be closed on grounds that it's *not a programming question*. I argue **it is a programming question** because the contents of an RPM SPEC file are an installation script that a developer must provide, and the question asks what are the correct, as envisioned by the distribution, installation commands for a specific target, CentOS 7 in this case. The [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/756099/389552) is a Unix question. It's not concerned with RPM specs at all, but with what a certain version of systemd is capable of. In this question, the developer needs not concern themselves with what systemd can do, but with *how* to provide the correct installation.